# How to iterate over a hash of sets

Tags: ruby, algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a hash that has the name of the players of a game as the key, and a set object containing the names of other players each player defeated as the value. The sets are initialized empty, then two players are picked at random and fight each other, the winner gets the other player key added to its set, representing victory over them. Once the victory is established, players can't fight each other again. Finally, a player that defeated another should also have on his set the players defeated by the other, and the others defeated by them, and so on.

In a given game situation there are 5 players, Claudia, Rosa, Bob, Carlos and Tim. Let's suppose Rosa defeats Bob, and then Bob defeats Carlos and Claudia defeats Tim the given data at this point would look like this:

```
@match_data = {"claudia"=>#<Set: {"tim">,
               "rosa"=>#<Set: {"bob", "carlos"}>,
               "bob"=>#<Set: {"carlos"},
               "carlos"=>#<Set: {},
               "tim"=>#<Set: {}}
```

So at this point Claudia has a victory against Tim so they will not have another battle, Rosa has a victory against Bob and Carlos thus she will never need to battle against them again, and Bob has against Carlos and they won't battle either. Imagine that after this, Bob defeats Claudia, the desired data at this moment should be:

```
@match_data = {"claudia"=>#<Set: {"tim"}>,
               "rosa"=>#<Set: {"bob", "carlos", "claudia", "tim"}>,
               "bob"=>#<Set: {"carlos", "claudia", "tim"},
               "carlos"=>#<Set: {},
               "tim"=>#<Set: {}}
```

When Bob defeats Claudia, he acquire not only the victory against her, but also against Tim which has been previously defeated, and more importantly, Rosa acquire the victory against Claudia and Tim, because she already has the victory against Bob. So in this case Rosa wins the game, Bob is second place, and the others are still playing. This can get more complicated because the number of players is not limited.

The problem I am trying to overcome is to create an function that will update the state of the game. Every time a match is over, this code will look at the match_data and find which victories have been acquired by the outcome of the match. This code is one of my attempts:

```
def update_set(key)
  store = Set.new
  @match_data[key].each { |value| store.merge @match_data[value] }
  if store.size > 0
    store.each { |value| update_set(value) }
  end
  @match_data[key].merge store
end

@match_data.sort.map do |key, set|
  update_set(key)
end
```

My other attempts get an error saying that I'm going too deep, or that I can't iterate a hash during a loop. Alternatively, I could try using another data structure, but I have no idea which one.

EDIT: I edited the original question just for clarity, as it was not clear what was my desired output when running my code. Nevertheless the answer given @ddubs works perfectly for my code.

Additionally, I would like to point a mistake at my given example, in my program the data could never really turn exactly as shown on the first code snippet, as the desired function would run always between each combat, refreshing the state of the dictionary then. I guess I did not want to write too much useless information and make my question more complex then it needed to be, but I ended up suppressing important information.

If needed I could post the whole program logic, but I don't think that this is necessary.

EDIT2: Added the whole game logic, as I found out it still wasn't clear enough, the solution given by @ddubs still works, but maybe someone can come with something better, now that all the information is given.

Comment: @sawa: would you please refrain from marking typos/misspellings with [sic] and instead just fix them? "sic" stands for "spelling is correct/intended", and you misuse it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, it means "just as it is". Okay, I won't use it, but the OP should be aware of how sloppy they are. That is not the right attitude when asking something to someone.

Comment: @sawa: ah, latin. In hindsight, it should have been obvious. In any case, thanks :)

Comment: @sawa I am a bit lost here, what do I have to correct on my text for it to be accepted as an eligible question? English is not my first language but I'm doing my best, I still can't see what is so wrong on the text.

Comment: @phbrasiliano Correction has already been done by Sergio. In some places, you have spelled the word correctly, but in some other places, you have not. This means that the misspelling was not due to English not being your first language, but was simply due to your carelessness.

Comment: What do you want if Bob beats Lisa, Lisa beats Tim and Tim beats Bob?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The information about who defeated who never enters the match_data hash at once, instead it goes one match at a time, so in the case you mentioned, Bob beats Lisa, then Lisa beats Tim, automatically  Bob would "acquire" the victory over Tim, and the game wouldn't allow a battle between both Bob and Tim happen (as the victor for this match has already been decided)

Comment: You need to define "hierarchy" in terms of a Ruby object. (Clarifications should be made by editing the question, rather than elaborating in comments, as not all readers read all comments.) Please also show the hierarchy (as a Ruby object) for the example you have given. More generally, when you give an example, show the desired output. Considering that each player does not play all other players, what would be the hierarchy if there were three players and two matches, with Bob and Lisa both beating Tim?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I changed the whole question to explain everything in a better way, I hope it helps because it took a while to rewrite everything, specially with my bad english. If anything is not clear I would gladly explain in even more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set's seem to make this a lil odd, or maybe its just the layout of the `@match_data` object. Anyways, this function has to be applied against each player and their corresponding set. It will also require that you pass the match data to it as well:

```
def compile_sets(set, data, results = Set.new)
  set.each do |s|
    results << s
    results << compile_sets(data[s], data, results)
  end
  results.flatten
end
```

Example Usage:

```
results = @match_data.map { |player,set| { player => compile_sets(set, @match_data) } }

p results
```

Returns:

```
[
  {"carlos"=>#<Set: {}>},
  {"bob"=>#<Set: {"carlos", "claudia"}>},
  {"lisa"=>#<Set: {"bob", "carlos", "claudia"}>},
  {"tim"=>#<Set: {"lisa", "bob", "carlos", "claudia"}>},
  {"mary"=>#<Set: {"lisa", "bob", "carlos", "claudia"}>},
  {"rosa"=>#<Set: {"tim", "lisa", "bob", "carlos", "claudia"}>}, 
  {"claudia"=>#<Set: {}>}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I was initially using arrays, and was determining the winners by the number of unique items on it. Searching for ways of making the items on the list unique, I found sets. Maybe not the right approach, but it was the one I could think of.

Comment: I edited my question to explain my problem in greater detail, so if you want to read and maybe think of another answer. But your answer still works perfectly for me :) I just had to add a line of code to convert the results array to a hash, and then replace the match_data:

`@match_data = results.reduce({}, :merge)`